# How to add a counter to a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have some code which asks the user to guess the answer to a calculation, and then either tells them they are correct or tries to identify where they went wrong. I have used a while loop in this but sometimes it gets stuck, is there a way to add a counter to the guesses taken, and to break the while loop after 5 incorrect guesses? Here is a section of my code so far:

```
#define correct answer for A
Ac=L*xm
#ask user to work out A (monthly interest * capital)
while True:
    A= raw_input("What do you think the monthly interest x the amount you are borrowing is? (please use 2 d.p.) £")
    A=float(A)
    #tell user if they are correct or not
    if A==round(Ac,2):
        print("correct")
        break
    elif A==round(L*x,2):
        print("incorrect. You have used the APR rate, whic is an annual rate, you should have used this rate divided by 12 to make it monthly")
        continue
    elif A==round(L/(x*100),2):
        print("incorrect. You have used the interest rate as a whole number when you should have used it as a decimal, and divided it by 12 for the monthly rate")
        continue
    else:
        print("Wrong, it seems you have made an error somewhere, you should have done the loan amount multiplied by the monthly rate")
        continue
```

Comment: I rolled back your edit, since most of the answers "build" on it. Removing it makes the whole thread a bit confusing. If you are unhappy with your code, feel free to alter it (and also alter the answer so they still make sense). You can @answer me if you do, then I can help accelerate the edit review process a little

Answer (score 8):

The standard library's [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.count) provide an iterator counting up:

```py
import itertools

for i in itertools.count():
    print(i)
```

You can set the `start` and `step`:

```
# count(10) --> 10 11 12 13 14 ...
# count(2.5, 0.5) --> 2.5 3.0 3.5 ...
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: If you want counter i to start on 1 use: it.count(start=1)

Answer (score 6):

The [Pythonic](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) way is

```
max_guesses = 5
solution = ... # Some solution
guessed = False
for wrong_guesses in range(1, max_guesses + 1):
    guess = ... # Get Guess
    if guess == round(solution, 2):
        print("correct")
        guessed = True
        break 
    ...
else:
    print(f"You have exceeded the maximum of {max_guesses} guesses")
```

This way the loop is executed at most `max_guesses` times. The `else` block is only executed if the loop did not end because of a `break` statement i.e. when there was no correct guess.

Note the `max_guesses + 1` because `range` is an iterator over the [interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) [low, high) (excluding the upper limit). So to run from 1 to max_guesses we have to +1.

Comment: if you let your range run from `1` to `max_guesses+1` you would not need the `guessed` variable, cutting a total of 4 lines. I think that would make your solution more readable (and pythonic), but thats just my opinion.
Alternatively, since the `wrong_guesses` is not used, you could just name it `_` and not care about on what value it ends

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comment. I chose this way to avoid the "max_guesses + 1" (which seemed more confusing, overall) and to make the guessed state explicit. I agree that your suggestion would make the code more concise though, and have updated the range so we can get rid of the last if (which was equally confusing, I guess)

Answer (score 4):

In general it should look like this:

```
i = 0
while i < max_guesses:
    i+=1
    # here is your code
```

Comment: this is not a good solution for python. Use a `for x in range()` loop instead

Comment: @Neuron is it not performant?

Comment: @Neuron I think this is perfectly good solution for python. Please provide more context, because I think this is just your style opinion.

Comment: @MaLiN2223 "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/ . For loops are created exactly for this one scenario. to iterate from start (usually 0) to finish with a certain step size (usually 1). for loops do *exactly* that and are the *perfect* tool to solve this problem

Comment: You might want to source your claims after the pep quote. Everything you wrote is just an opinion. 
I doubt any of creators of python said 'For loops are created exactly for this one scenario'

Answer (score 2):

Just create a variable to store the amount of incorrect guesses and use an if condition to detect when user guessed wrong 5 times, then stop the loop. As shown below:

```
Ac=L*xm
incorrect_guesses = 0 # variable to store incorrect guesses
# ask user to work out A (monthly interest * capital)
while True:
    if incorrect_guesses == 5:
        break # stop loop
    else: # if not, continue normally
        guess = raw_input("What do you think the monthly interest x the amount you are borrowing is? (please use 2 d.p.) £")
        guess = float(guess)
        # tell user if they are correct or not
        if guess == round(Ac, 2):
            print("correct")
            break
        elif guess == round(L * x, 2):
            print("incorrect. You have used the APR rate, which is an annual rate, you should have used this rate divided by 12 to make it monthly")
            incorrect_guesses += 1
        elif A == round(L / (x * 100), 2):
            print("incorrect. You have used the interest rate as a whole number when you should have used it as a decimal, and divided it by 12 for the monthly rate")
            incorrect_guesses += 1
        else:
            print("Wrong, it seems you have made an error somewhere, you should have done the loan amount multiplied by the monthly rate")
            incorrect_guesses += 1
```